# Why does my hamburger menu not work when I click it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't find problem, why hamburger menu doesn't work when I click it. It should show mobile menu on the right site of mobile screen. When I click hamburger nothing happens. What can I try to resolve this?

```js
    const mobileNav = document.querySelector(".lista")
    const burger = document.querySelector(".fa-solid")
    
    
    const funkcja = () => {
        mobileNav.classList.toggle("active")
    }
    
    burger.addEventListener("click", funkcja)
```

```css
    * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    html{
        font-size: 10px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     
    }
    
    
    
    .logo {
        width: 23vh;
    }
    
    /* Nav styling */ 
    
    nav {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(186, 184, 182, 0.694);
        height: 20vh;
        position: relative;
    
    }
    
    ul {
        display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      text-align: center;
      width: 80%;
      text-decoration: none;
      list-style: none;
 
    }
    
    a {
        font-size: 2rem;
        
        text-decoration: none;
    
    }
    
    
    
    .fa-solid  {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .galeria {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 5px;
    
    }
    img {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px){
    ul {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20vh;
        right: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: blueviolet;
        width: 150px;
        transition: 1s;
        transform: translate(100%);
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    .fa-solid {
        display: block;
        color: blueviolet;
        font-size: 70px;
    }
    
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
        ul {
            width: 100%;
            
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8849951a46.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Hamburgerek</title>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="dupa">
    <img class="logo" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/11/16/16/41/web-1045994_1280.jpg" alt="">
    
    
    
    <ul class="lista">
        <li><a href="#">Strona Główna</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cennik</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
    <script src="/Users/mateuszszyca/html/nowy/js.js"></script>
        </nav>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Because the list is along the burger button. Just debug with F12 and check the position. You can hover over the HTML elementos.

Comment: can you tell me what code should I write?

Answer (score 2):

I have commented the changes for you.  you are giving `active class` to the `ul` but not defining it in the `css`.the reason you couldn't see you nav list because you were using overflow hidden in global selector `*{overflow:hidden}`.i hope this solves your issue.

```js
const mobileNav = document.querySelector(".lista")
const burger = document.querySelector(".fa-solid")

burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
  mobileNav.classList.toggle("active")
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* overflow:hidden */
  /* Removed */
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.logo {
  width: 23vh;
  height: 100%;
  /* Added */
}


/* Nav styling */

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(186, 184, 182, 0.694);
  height: 20vh;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fa-solid {
  display: none;
}

.galeria {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 23vh;
    /* added */
    right: 10px;
    /* added */
    display: flex;
    visibility: hidden;
    /* added */
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    width: 0px;
    /* for animation */
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: width 0.25s ease-in-out;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  ul.active {
    visibility: visible;
    /* added */
    width: 150px;
  }
  .fa-solid {
    display: block;
    color: blueviolet;
    font-size: 4rem;
    /* changed from px to rem for better responsiveness */
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  ul {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8849951a46.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <body>
    <nav class="dupa">
      <img class="logo" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/11/16/16/41/web-1045994_1280.jpg" alt="">



      <ul class="lista">
        <li><a href="#">Strona Główna</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cennik</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
      </ul>

      <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
      <script src="/Users/mateuszszyca/html/nowy/js.js"></script>
    </nav>
  </body>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const mobileNav = document.querySelector(".lista")
    const burger = document.querySelector(".fa-solid")
    
    
    const funkcja = () => {
        mobileNav.classList.toggle("active")
    }
    
    burger.addEventListener("click", funkcja)
```

```css
* {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html{
        font-size: 10px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     
    }
    
    
    
    .logo {
        width: 23vh;
    }
    
    /* Nav styling */ 
    
    nav {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(186, 184, 182, 0.694);
        height: 20vh;
        position: relative;
    
    }
    
    ul {
        display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      text-align: center;
      width: 80%;
      text-decoration: none;
      list-style: none;
      
    
    }
    
    a {
        font-size: 2rem;
        
        text-decoration: none;
    
    }
    
    
    
    .fa-solid  {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .galeria {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 5px;
    
    }
    img {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px){
    ul {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20vh;
        right: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: blueviolet;
        width: 150px;
        transition: 1s;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    
    
    
    .fa-solid {
        display: block;
        color: blueviolet;
        font-size: 70px;
    }
    
    
    
    
    }
    
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
        ul {
            width: 100%;
            
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8849951a46.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Hamburgerek</title>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="dupa">
    <img class="logo" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/11/16/16/41/web-1045994_1280.jpg" alt="">
    
    
    
    <ul class="lista">
        <li><a href="#">Strona Główna</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cennik</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
    <script src="/Users/mateuszszyca/html/nowy/js.js"></script>
        </nav>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: remove overflow:hidden; from *{} and for javascript you didn't add active class so first add an active class then the function will work.

Comment: Add the explanation inside the post, not in a comment, please. You can edit it with the "Edit" button below it. Btw the solution is not working.

Comment: In css you used *{  overflow: hidden; }  means "all elements" if it overflow then hide data. ul tag is showing on  the position where you want it to show but it's hidden due to navbar overflow.